# How to construct a 3D avatar with 3D coordinates of human joints

Tags: model, 3d

I now have 3D coordinate data of 32 joints of one person.
For short, I want to visualize the pose with a 3D model whose skeleton system and mesh materials are supplied by the ones downloaded from the website.
I want to know the methods of constructing models with coordinates by python. And output the constructed model as .fbx .glb format.
Thanks.

I have tried to use PyWeb3D to apply three.js to python, while there's something wrong with the visualization of the model in html page (maybe the problem of importing the packages).
I want to try some easier methods of constructing 3D models.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please add some context to your question by adding your attempted code. See [mre] for more details.